# Set value configuration.GetSection("").Value from header request

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to set in my asp.net core configuration a value from the header in every request.
I'm doing like so:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var companyId = context.Request.Headers["companyid"].ToString().ToUpper();
        configuration.GetSection("CompanyId").Value = companyId;

        await next(context);           
    }
```

It works fine. But is this the proper way? In case of multiple request at same time is there a risk of messing the values? I've searched around but couldn't find an answer.

I'm using .Net 3.1.

Comment: How do you expect it to work when the service restarts or if when the request hits a different service instance? Sounds like you need a persistent storage to store this value

Comment: This value will be passed in every request. I don't have the need to store it. I'll take a decision based on value received from this request.

Comment: Then why try to modify the application's configuration at all? `CompanyID` is just data that needs to be passed along to other methods.

Comment: I think, for my case I can use IHttpContextAccessor.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the appsetting.json value is a global setting value, you shouldn't be modifying global state per request, this action is not thread safe. At some point, you will face a rice condition.

If you still want to use this codes, I suggest you could try to add a lock.  Notice: This will make your Invoke method very slowly.

Details, you could refer to below codes:

```
    private static Object _factLock = new Object();

        lock (_factLock)
        {
            Configuration.GetSection("CompanyId").Value = "";

        }
```

Comment: So, how to make this value available globally without passing it method after until the point I need it?

Comment: I think, for my case I can use IHttpContextAccessor.

Comment: In my opinion, this is based on your requirement.  Normally, we don't suggest you to modify the appsetting value for each request. We could read it from the appsetting and then use it in your application. If you want to modify it according to each user, I suggest you could try to store the value into httpcontext like cookie or session and use it based on each user.